# What was the inspiration for April O'Neils ultimate fate in the original TMNT Mirage comics?

Tags: inspiration, teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles, april-o-neil, take-on-me

I'm digging into the history of April O'Neil, and I've just found out how her story ends in the original Mirage comics, or if not 'ends' then a major story point for her.

> With the help of Renet, a time-traveler who took April back through time, it was revealed that April was really a living drawing brought to life with the help of Kirby's crystal.

Was this at all inspired by the 1984 music video for Take On Me, by A-ha? If not what was the inspiration?

Comment: Drawings coming to life are a lot older than that "Take On Me" video, although the video was unquestionably influential.

Comment: @buzz absolutely it was influential, and just about the right era.

Comment: It was the first video I ever saw on MTV.